# How to send (emulate) keybinding to webContents in electron?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, browser, electron, key-bindings

I'm building electron application that makes a desktop interface for a website. On the website, I already have registered keybindings, like `Shift+?` that shows the table of all available keybindings.

I have to create an app menu of actions that correspond to the keybindings. Technically, when a user clicks on a menu item, it should trigger the keybinding on a webpage. Example:

> When user press **Help** on the menu → `Shift+?` keybinding is being triggered → webpage detects `keypress` → webpage shows the table of all registered keybindings appears.

The problem is that I can't send the `Shift+?` keybinding to the `webContents`. These attempts are failing:

```
webContents.sendInputEvent({type:'char', keyCode: 'Shift+?' });
webContents.sendInputEvent({type:'keydown', keyCode: 'Shift+?' });
webContents.sendInputEvent({type:'keyup', keyCode: 'Shift+?'});
```

How can I force the webpage to perform an action based on specific keybinding (a.k.a send keybinding to the webpage)?

**UPD:** I've found out few details. The order of events should be `keyDown`, `char`, `keyUp`. I made a handy function for sending keybindings:

```
function sendKeybinding(win, keyCode) {
  win.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'keyDown', keyCode });
  win.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'char', keyCode });
  win.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'keyUp', keyCode });
}
```

The `MenuItem` that uses this might look like this:

```
{
  label: 'Show Keymap',
  accelerator: ['Shift+/', '?'],
  click(menuItem, browserWindow) {
    sendKeybinding(browserWindow, '?');
  },
}
```

Also, there is a hatch in a case with `Shift+?`: `?` can be entered only with `Shift` pressed, so actually, there is a two accelerators `Shift+/` and `?`.

However, I still don't know how to enter the keybinding like `CmdOrControl+B`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `modifiers` property of argument object?  Like `modifiers = []; modifiers.push('shift'); sendInputEvents({type: 'keyDown', modifiers, keyCode}) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to the event order you found out, you can use the `modifiers` property of `sendInputEvents` argument to send shift/ctrl/alt etc. modifiers with the key input. *See [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendinputeventevent) for further details*

With the following code HTML can detect the shortcut you want:

*main.js*

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function sendKeybinding (win, keyCode) {
  let modifiers = []
  modifiers.push('shift') // 'control', 'meta', etc.
  win.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'keyDown', modifiers, keyCode })
  win.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'char', modifiers, keyCode })
  win.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'keyUp', modifiers, keyCode })
}

app.on('ready', function () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL(path.resolve(__dirname, 'keybind.html'))
  const menuTemplate = [
    {
      label: 'Show Keymap',
      click (menuItem, browserWindow) {
        sendKeybinding(browserWindow, '?')
      }
    }
  ]
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate)
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
})
```

*keybind.html*

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Pressed Key: </p>
<script>
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("demo")
  elem.innerHTML = 'Pressed Key: ' + event.key
  if (event.shiftKey) elem.innerHTML += ' + Shift '
  if (event.ctrlKey) elem.innerHTML += ' + Ctrl '
  if (event.metaKey) elem.innerHTML += ' + Win/Cmd '
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like it works for `Shift`. However, how can I handle `Cmd` keypress?

Comment: It's going to map to [`event.metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey) on html side, so add modifier `meta` (but i don't have mac, cannot test)

Comment: @pergy i need ctrl+wheel, but replacing the 2nd input with 'mouseWheel' event doesn't work, any possible reasons? (already changed modifiers Shift -> Ctrl)

Comment: @Dee you may miss event properties like delta, canscroll etc. See possible properties [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/structures/mouse-wheel-input-event)